# Storing data from database to javascript using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to the [Laravel Framework](https://laravel.com/). I tried to store data from a database to javascript using this framework. Here is my code.

```
var customers = [];
@foreach($data as $store)
var tobeStored = {
   id: {{$store->id}},
   name: {{$store->name}},
   contact: {{$store->contact_no}},
   latitude: {{$store->lat}},
   longtitude{{$store->lng}},
   address: {{$store->address}}
};
customers.push(tobeStored);
@endforeach
alert(customers.length);
```

Comment: Please add your code in the question here and please explain how/why you plan on storing data in javascript? That does not make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add quote before echo your data like this.

```
name : '{{$store->name}}'
```

But we can't help you more, without any error or code.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked! Been problematic about this for days.

Comment: You're welcome, but next time, please paste plain text code, and display errors, this sould help us to help you

Comment: Sorry, honestly i tried to paste it, but it got some errors when posting. I'm still struggling on formats about posting questions.